# streaming cassandra data using nodejs with scale

Tags: node.js, cassandra, scaling

I have a requirement to read millions of records stored in cassandra using nodejs.

I have already got the streaming nodejs service ready for reading stream by stream from cassandra and pushing the data to an analytics server (streaming service again).

However, I am not sure how to achieve horizontal scaling of nodejs layer where multiple instance of nodejs apps keep reading from cassandra WITHOUT DUPLICATION and serve it to the analytics server.

Any help on this will be of great help.

Thanks.